# How can Vision be used to identify visible face landmarks?

Tags: ios, swift, vision

I've been using Vision to identify Facial Landmarks, using `VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest`.

It seems that whenever a face is detected, the resulting `VNFaceObservation` will always contain all the possible landmarks, and have positions for all of them. It also seems that positions returned for the occluded landmarks are 'guessed' by the framework.

I have tested this using a photo where the subject's face is turned to the left, and the left eye thus isn't visible. Vision returns a left eye landmark, along with a position.

Same thing with the mouth and nose of a subject wearing a N95 face mask, or the eyes of someone wearing opaque sunglasses.

While this can be a useful feature for other use cases, is there a way, using Vision or CIDetector, to figure which face landmarks actually are visible on a photo?

I also tried using CIDetector, but it appears to be able to detect mouths and smiles through N95 masks, so it doesn't seem to be a reliable alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After confirmation from Apple, it appears it simply cannot be done.
If Vision detects a face, it will guess some occluded landmarks' positions, and there is no way to differentiate actually detected landmarks from guesses.

For those facing the same issue, a partial way around can be to compare the landmarks' points' positions to those of the median line's and the nose crest's points.

While this can help determine if a facial landmark is occluded by the face itself, it won't help with facial landmarks occluded by opaque sunglasses or face masks.